# Failing to get docker to work with react and webpack

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile

So, I've been working on this problem for the better part of a week now and I feel like I've gotten nowhere despite reading a lot of articles on this very topic and reading through a lot of stack overflow questions. I've got the following files `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile.dev` that I'm trying to use in following this article, https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/dockerize-your-app-and-keep-hot-reloading. A few differences between my implementation and that article. I can't use the node_modules directory as far as I'm aware from my machine (OSX), as I'm trying to run Docker with a linux environment, so I have to run `npm install` from within Docker. I don't have an api implemented yet (that is coming, I just want to get this to work first), so all references to `api` have been removed.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    links:
      - app:app
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ../retail
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ../retail:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
  db:
    container_name: database
    build: ./database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: supersecretpasswordthatnobodyknows
      POSTGRES_USER: devsuperuser
      POSTGRES_DB: lending
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And this is my Dockerfile.dev referenced above:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./.npmrc ./

RUN npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-server webpack-hot-client -g
RUN npm link webpack webpack-dev-server && npm install

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Some of the things I've tried are in the above code. Such as setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to `false`. And installing everything `webpack` globally and then linking it. I found if I didn't do the latter I got errors about not being able to find webpack. I've tried multiple combinations of different ideas from a whole host of articles, but no matter what I've tried I'm constantly getting issues about some missing module or another.

I'm just wondering if someone can help me make this article work for me while needing to do an `npm install`. Or perhaps even some way that I can do the `npm install` locally and not need to do it in the Docker container (because that works).

EDIT:
I'm adding another file and part of a file that may or may not be relevant below in response to a comment asking for them.

`webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    // 'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:9000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: false,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/v1': {
        target: 'an IP address',
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|woff|woff2|ttff|eot|ttf)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for Webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
          // plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /config\.js$/,
        loaders: 'string-replace-loader',
        query: {
          multiple: [
            { search: '{{API_SERVER}}', replace: '' },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: { postcss: [autoprefixer] } }),
  ],
};
```

And my script definition for `start:dev` in my `package.json`

```
"start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --hot --inline",
```

Comment: maybe not helpful, but if this is for local dev, do you even care whether the node app is containerized? sounds like problems in relative pathing in webpack dev server, but you can run this just as easily outside the container. if you're worried about shipping/production, you will be building the app anyway, and removing webpack server from the equation.

Comment: @baku That's currently what we're doing. However we're utilizing servers for development environments (strictly for testing on an actual server, everyone actually develops locally and then pushes to the dev environment) and then for QA environments. I'd like to get away from that and just use Docker locally. In addition, this will help guarantee that every Dev and every QA is using the same consistent environment all the time.

Comment: makes sense, just note that webpack-dev-server served apps can behave differently than built (IME), so it would still make sense to me to, in your dockerized dev/QA servers, to be running the built code via npm run build.    

Anyway, back to your actual question: perhaps someone with more knowledge will be able to help you directly, but if you can share a cleaned version of the app (i.e. project structure, package.json etc without any sensitive/proprietary code), I would be happy to try and run this locally, and/compare it our k8s builds templates. maybe i can catch something you've missed

Comment: @baku I have edited my original question to include my webpack.config.js and the script in my package.json. Admittedly it's doubtful having my dependencies will help, as we are loading everything from an internal repository and not an official npm repo. A big part of the reason for this is to enable hot reloading for developers using this as their local dev environment, and be able to get rid of all the documentation on how to create your environment (there's more to come, a lot more), and boil it down to a simple one line docker command to get up and running.